# How can I clear text in another text view when I have entered text in auto complete text view and cleared it in android?

Tags: java, android

```
This is my code....


package com.appdest.geoalarm;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

@SuppressLint({ "ShowToast", "NewApi" })
public class PlacesActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener,
        OnValueChangeListener {

    TextView setAlarm, distance_calc;
    ImageView current_location;
    EditText from_location;
    ImageButton track;
    double dist;

    Context context = null;
    AutoCompleteTextView tvToLocation;
    PlacesTask placesTask;
    ParserTask parserTask;
    LinearLayout llTrack;

    String fromAddress, toAddress;
    final static int RQS_1 = 1;
    float lat2, log2, lat1, log1;
    List<Address> list;
    Double Distance;
    int number;
    LatLng dest, orgin;

    Location locations;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    Criteria criteria;
    Geocoder gc;
    String provider;
    List<Address> address1 = null;
    String s, Distances;
    String PREF_FILE = "pref store";
    AlertDialog Alarm, dialog;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.places);

        tvToLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.to_location);
        tvToLocation.setThreshold(1);
        tvToLocation.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tvToLocation.getWindowToken(), 0);

                // String Name="Mani";
                //
                // distance_calc.setText(Name);

                if (tvToLocation != null) {
                    tvToLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.to_location);

                    fromAddress = from_location.getText().toString();
                    toAddress = tvToLocation.getText().toString();

                    try {
                        address1 = gc.getFromLocationName(toAddress, 5);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (address1 == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Address location1 = address1.get(0);
                    lat2 = (float) location1.getLatitude();
                    log2 = (float) location1.getLongitude();

                    orgin = new LatLng(lat1, log1);
                    dest = new LatLng(lat2, log2);

                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(orgin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);

                    distance_calc.setText(null);

                }

                else {
                    distance_calc.setText(null);
                }
            }

        });

        track = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.trackmyway);
        setAlarm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm);
        distance_calc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
        llTrack = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llTrack);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            try {
                lat1 = (float) location.getLatitude();
                log1 = (float) location.getLongitude();

                orgin = new LatLng(lat1, log1);

                gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                address1 = gc.getFromLocation(lat1, log1, 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                    Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat1, log1,
                        1);
                if (addresses != null) {
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");
                    for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress
                            .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strReturnedAddress.append(
                                returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");

                        s = new StringBuilder().append(strReturnedAddress)
                                .toString();

                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not ", 40).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Canont get Address ",
                        40).show();
            }

        }

        tvToLocation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                placesTask = new PlacesTask();
                placesTask.execute(s.toString());

                if (tvToLocation == null && tvToLocation.length()<=0) {
                    distance_calc.setText(null);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

                if (tvToLocation == null && tvToLocation.length()<=0) {
                    distance_calc.setText(null);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (tvToLocation == null  && tvToLocation.length()<=0) {
                    distance_calc.setText(null);
                }

            }

        });

//      distance_calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//
//              if (from_location.length() == 0 && tvToLocation.length() == 0) {
//                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                          "Please enter the locations", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                          .show();
//              } else {
//
//                  calculateDistance();
//              }
//          }
//      });

        from_location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.from_location);

        // current location
        current_location = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.current_location);
        current_location.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                from_location.setText(s);

            }
        });

        setAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final CharSequence[] items = { " By Time ", " By Distance " };

                // Creating and Building the Dialog
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        PlacesActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Set Alarm");
                builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                                switch (item) {
                                case 0:
                                    openTimePickerDialog(true);

                                    break;
                                case 1:

                                    openDistanceDialog();
                                    break;

                                }
                                Alarm.dismiss();
                            }

                        });
                Alarm = builder.create();
                Alarm.show();

            }
        });

        llTrack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (from_location.length() == 0 && tvToLocation.length() == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please Select the Locations", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else {

                    SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE,
                            MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = spref.edit();

                    edit.putString("toaddress", toAddress);
                    edit.putFloat("srcLat", lat1);
                    edit.putFloat("srcLong", log1);
                    edit.putFloat("destLat", lat2);
                    edit.putFloat("destLong", log2);
                    edit.putInt("distanceNumber", number);
                    edit.commit();

                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    // "Please select the vehicle you are travelling by",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent map = new Intent(PlacesActivity.this,
                            MapTrackingActivity.class);
                    startActivity(map);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                PlacesActivity.this, onTimeSetListener,
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), is24r);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");

        timePickerDialog.show();

    }

    OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
                // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            alarmSet(calSet);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm is set",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        private void alarmSet(Calendar calSet) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(PlacesActivity.this, Receiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent);

        }
    };

    private void openDistanceDialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Dialog dialogue = new Dialog(PlacesActivity.this);
        dialogue.setTitle("Distance");
        dialogue.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        Button btset = (Button) dialogue.findViewById(R.id.btSet);
        Button btcancel = (Button) dialogue.findViewById(R.id.btCancel);
        final NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) dialogue
                .findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);

        numberPicker.setMaxValue(10); // max value 10
        numberPicker.setMinValue(0); // min value 1
        numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
        numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
        btset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                number = numberPicker.getValue();
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the Value is"+number
                // , 50).show();

                dialogue.dismiss();
            }
        });
        btcancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogue.dismiss(); // dismiss the dialog
            }
        });
        dialogue.show();
        dialogue.getWindow().setLayout(400, 550);

    }

    public class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            String[] from = new String[] { "description" };
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
            tvToLocation.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }

    public class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String data = "";
            String key = "key=AIzaSyCX9JAUF6C_U0FGCvGMM26bLyGptYtl3Ok";
            String input = "";

            try {
                input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            String types = "types=geocode";
            String sensor = "sensor=false";
            String parameters = input + "&" + types + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;
            String output = "json";
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"
                    + output + "?" + parameters;

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service in background
                data = downloadUrl(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Creating ParserTask
            parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    protected void calculateDistance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tvToLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.to_location);

        fromAddress = from_location.getText().toString();
        toAddress = tvToLocation.getText().toString();

        try {
            address1 = gc.getFromLocationName(toAddress, 5);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (address1 == null) {
            return;
        }
        Address location1 = address1.get(0);
        lat2 = (float) location1.getLatitude();
        log2 = (float) location1.getLongitude();

        orgin = new LatLng(lat1, log1);
        dest = new LatLng(lat2, log2);

        String url = getDirectionsUrl(orgin, dest);

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        downloadTask.execute(url);

    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng orgin, LatLng dest) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str_origin = "origin=" + orgin.latitude + "," + orgin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
                + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;
    }

    private String downloadUrl1(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    iStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String data = "";
            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl1(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            RouteParser parserTask = new RouteParser();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    public class RouteParser extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            // PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            // MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";
            if (result.size() < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                // lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    if (j == 0) { // Get distance from the list
                        distance = (String) point.get("distance");


                        continue;
                    } else if (j == 1) { // Get duration from the list
                        // duration = (String) point.get("duration");
                        continue;
                    }


                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);


                    if (tvToLocation.length() > 0 && tvToLocation != null) {
                        distance_calc.setText(distance);
                    }
                    else

                        distance_calc.setText(null);
                }
                }

            }


    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + newVal, 50).show();

    }

}
```

Here in this code when I give  current location normally and destination from autocomplete textview distance is automatically appeared in text view..

So when I clear the text in autocomplete textview ,automatically already appeared distance should be cleared?Can u explain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set `addTextChangedListener` on editText and check editText's string length in its overrided method `afterTextChanged`. if string length is Zero than clear the distance field

Comment: Thank u its working...I have used this..as What u Said..public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if (s.length() == 0) {
     distance_calc.setText("Show Distance");
    }

   }

Answer (score 0):

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

```
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                distance_calc.setText("Show Distance");
            }

        }
```

Now it's working.....